# How would i leave out the name jones but display people with the same deptno

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

```
SQL> select empno, ename, deptno
  2  from empcopy
  3  where deptno =
  4      (select deptno
  5       from empcopy
  6       where ename like 'JONES');

 EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO
------ ---------- ----------
  7369 SMITH              20
  7566 JONES              20
  7788 SCOTT              20
  7876 ADAMS              20
  7902 FORD               20
```

Comment: the line `7566 JONES              20` should be removed, shouldn't be?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
select 
empno, ename, deptno
from empcopy 
where DEPTNO in (select DEPTNO  from empcopy where ename ='JONES')
and ename <>'JONES'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add a predicate to your where clause to exclude Jones.

```
SELECT
  empno,
  ename,
  deptno
  FROM
  empcopy
 WHERE
  deptno =(SELECT
             deptno
             FROM
             empcopy
            WHERE
             ename LIKE 'JONES'
          )
  AND ename != 'JONES';
```

Comment: Not equal to is <> or !=  In SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with jones as
  2    (select ename, deptno
  3     from emp
  4     where ename = 'JONES'
  5    )
  6  select e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno
  7  from emp e join jones j on e.deptno = j.deptno and e.ename <> j.ename;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH              20
      7788 SCOTT              20
      7876 ADAMS              20
      7902 FORD               20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option uses self-join including inequality for the values of `ename` column :

```
select e1.empno, e1.ename, e1.deptno
  from employees e1
  join employees e2 
    on e1.deptno = e2.deptno
   and e2.ename = 'JONES'
   and e1.ename != e2.ename
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b9c4cf704fecedc39eb0b226e69315c)</kbd>